# which stepper motor driver is best for robotic arm?

Tags: stepper-motor, robotics, stepper-driver

I am  building a robot arm am using TB6560and [datasheet](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/info/docget.jsp?did=28726&prodName=TB6560AHQ),with stepper motor 17HS3001-20B datasheet.

I have problem with the stop current setting i.e. when stop the driver tb6560 reduces current supplied to motor by 50%.

This reduces the holding torque in stop position(when no signal is given by arduino).

I want increase holding torque as well as torque in running condition .

Is there any setting in tb6560 to set dip s2 for required current setting ,because tb6560 board that is only have two option i.i 20 % and 50% of running current.

Should this problem can resolve with TB6560 or I change driver to TB6600 or any other driver like L298 ,A4998 or any better solution .

I am using 12/24 volt and max 3A.

THANKS

[image: Tb6560 drvier on my setup]

Comment: Please add proper punctuation/capitalization to your post, it's very difficult to read.

Comment: Man, if you are making a robotic arm, why stepper? Any normal robot uses brushless motor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just bad documentation on the part of the board manufacturer.
The setting you point to is to do with the rate of change of switch current and NOT the torque setting when stationary.

My recommendation is:

1. Read the [datasheet](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/408/TB6560AHQ_datasheet_en_20141001-771503.pdf) on Decay Mode and Torque settings.
2. Use only switches SW1, SW2, SW3 to set the winding current. This is non intuitive, but what they did was include Decay in the current settings and simply confuse the settings issues.
3. Set S1=S2=Off ...this is Normal 0% rate change speed (these are DCY1, 2)
4. Set S5=S6=Off ...this is Normal 0% fallback Torque setting (these are TQ1, 2)

Just to make sure....here's an image of the ones I have:

[image]

I did some measurements on a board using a 3A 2.8 Ohm Long Stepper motor with a 24 Volt power supply. 
I hooked the inputs to an Arduino Nano running Kiss-Stepper as a test utility.
All DIP switches (1-6) to OFF
I measured the current on Full step just after turnon.

Results were as follows:
Supply Current 220 mA    Winding(V) 1.6   Target Current 2 A  Actual 1.65 A
Supply Current 370 mA    Winding(V) 2.2   Target Current 3 A  Actual 2 A

Hope this helps.

Comment: It try to run motor with this setting but motor does not rotate when signal is given by arduino and is stationary condition it offer no resistance to rotation as it give when i set as per documentation.

Comment: Are you Enabling the board? You need three signals to activate the board; CLK, CW/CCW and EN. When you first turn on the board the power and Run LED's should be on and you should have +100% current in the A winding and -100% current in the B winding.

Comment: I am confused about connection of enable pin.
can you post a connection diagram of your setup to understand better .

Comment: I simply hooked EN- to Gnd and EN+ to VCC (there's a 300 Ohm resistor in series with the input LED) on an Arduino when I tested it. I'll hook one up tomorrow and check for you.

Comment: Please share your arduino code with pin connections from arduino to 6560.Does AccelStepper library for Arduino is good to use with tb6560.

Comment: I am getting 0.9A at 12volts.

Comment: I am making ENABLE pin low through arduino .All dip switches are at off position.when motor rotate there is about 3.3A supplied to motor . I want share pics of my setup ,what shoud I do.

Comment: Added my measurements to the answer. My bad I got the Enable wrong, you turn it on to disable.

Comment: I am not able to understand your measurement ,If I am right your motor is not taking rated current to generate rated torque.
Should I define ENABLE pin HIGH (5V) .
Thanks for your efforts this is helping me to understand this ic , arduino and electronics as new learner.

Comment: The current definition for the device is Peak current through the H-bridge switches. Since the PWM  turns off when the peak current is reached (you then have to dissipate the energy stored in the winding before turning on again) the current in the winding will always be significantly less than the peak current. How much less depends on several factors related to duty cycle including the Cosc setup for the board. In short when you set  3 A on the board, you will not get 3 A RMS through the winding. A good point to start is that you will get around 50-70% depending on PWM duty cycle.

Comment: In my measurements I got 82% @ 2A and 66% @ 3 A. This is dependent with this device on the frequency of Cosc. Depending on the frequency used in your board (they vary considerably) if your set DIP switch 5, 6 On then you may actually be able to hear the switching frequency from the stepper.

Answer (score 0):

> You may be out of luck and have to reduce acceleration maximums instead.

The stop current is reduced to prevent overheating of the chip with in one state rather than moving with 50% duty cycle at full current.

Accelerating and braking currents depend on torque and inertial load affects duration.  The arm requires more torque by mechanical ratios.

It seems you may have underestimated the driver resistance need for your load. This IC is TB6560AHQ: 0.6 Ω (typ.)  TB6560AFG: 0.7 Ω (typ.)

My rule of thumb is since most efficient motors have a surge current 10x rated current due to inductance/DCR ratio of motor coil.

The Pd rating of the driver must compared to Pd of the motor such that the ratio of RdsOn and DCR of the motor coil is low. As current flows thru both and Pd is proportional to R, the power and R ratios may be compared to ensure excellent torque.  This means getting drivers capable of running higher power motors to increase holding power when mechanical ratios of the arm and its extended force, demand longer high torque periods where current is well above rated current depending on RPM with back EMF.

Comment: How can I select a stepper motor and driver for my robotic arm .

Comment: Define torque and acceleration to size motor.